# How to change OneMenu element to outputText in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I would like my page to be user friendly as much as possible and I have an idea but its a little bit harder in the way I want to solve it.

I'm using primefaces and I would like to have a selectOneMenu element which changes to just an outputText with the value of the selected variable in the selectOneMenu. Anyone have some nifty ideas?

Comment: On value change it can be disabled, if your intention is to disallow user from selecting value second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with ajax and partial rendering. Here is a sketch of my idea (untested and in plain JSF):

```
<h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.myValue}" 
                   rendered="#{myBean.myValue == someInitialValue}" ...>
     <f:ajax render="wrapper"/>
       ... (your select items here)
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <h:outputText value="#{myBean.myValue}" 
                rendered="#{myBean.myValue != someInitialValue}" .../>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And that's what it does:

The value of `h:selectOneMenu` will be initialized and the menu will be rendered only if it is the initial value.

On change of the value, the surrounding panelgroup will be re-rendered, hides the menu and lets the `h:outputText` appear.

You need a wrapping panelGroup for this because the outputText is not there at page load. If your form is small you could also `render=@form` or any other surrounding container instead. Then you wouldn't need the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was thinking in the same way, but I thought there is maybe some primefaces attribute that can help minimize the code.

Comment: Yes this would be a good addition, something like [Inplace](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/inplace.jsf) for selectOneMenu.... EDIT: Oh, Just noticed that there is a select menu on the given link. Maybe you should take a closer look at this example.